# Javascript- Make an image appear then replace it with another image (blinking)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a car park map image, and I have an image for each car park spot with a big red circle around the spot, essentially the same map image with just a red circle around a spot.

I am trying to make a blinking image effect where I have the first map image and then replace it with the new map image that has a red circle around a spot.

**HTML**

```
<div id="map">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var img = document.getElementById('map').innerHtml = '<img id="map" src="../../images/Map.png" class="img-responsive" width="800" height="600"/>';
var img2 = document.getElementById('map').innerHtml = '<img id ="map2" src="../../images/<?php $location = "B04"; echo $location;?>.png" class="img-responsive" width="800" height="600">';
var i = 2;

var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    if((img.style.visibility == 'hidden')&&(img2.style.visibility == 'visible')){
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
        img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }else{
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        img2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}, 1000); 
}
```

How do I go about making an image appear, then be removed from HTML, replaced with a new one and then brought back again, as in blinking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew what you mean and it seems interesting.

It is OK to just change the src of the image directly without setting the visibility, by setting intervals. It also shows the effect of blinking.

You don't need to change the innerHTML of the map. DIV is too additional.

**HTML**

```
<!--I simplified the code. Don't use this code in production -->
<html>
<script src="code.js"></script>
<body onload="onloadfun()">
<!--you can set this image to be a loading image for reference.-->
<img src="loading.gif" id="map"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var flip = false;
function onloadfun(){
    setInterval(function(){update();},1000);
}

function update(){
    var node = document.getElementById("map");
    if(flip){
        node.src = "map2.png";
        flip = false;
    } else {
        node.src = " map.png";
        flip = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Love how you went about it, thanks very much that was driving me crazy! :D

Comment: There is another method to do this by rendering a transparent circle on the map. This may be more stable than changing the map directly. But two methods are also okay.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try out a CSS3 approach and just use JavaScript/jQuery to position your blinking images to anywhere you want.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrqMbO

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://bushbyre.e1.siteloft.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Tamar_ST_MAP.jpg" class="park-img" />
  <img src="http://anspachmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/full-circle.png" class="icon" />
  <img src="http://anspachmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/full-circle.png" class="icon2" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.icon, .icon2 {
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;

  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

.park-img {
  width: 500px;
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  100% { opacity: 0.0; }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery( function($) {

    $('.icon').css({
        left: '243px',
        top: '160px'
    });

    $('.icon2').css({
        left: '455px',
        top: '70px'
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

really easy to do, check out this jsfiddle:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yrg80we/)

```
(function() {
   var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

window.setInterval(function(){
  if(img1.style.display == "block"){
    img1.style.display = "none";
    img2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    img1.style.display = "block";
    img2.style.display = "none";
  }
}, 1000);

})();
```